# Change a string by using a prototype setter function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to execute a function when I change a variable, such as:

```
x = "Hello, World"
//console.log("Your value changed to: ", val)
```

I am looking at the prototypes of variables and setter functions. Is there a way to use both of these to attach a setter function to when the actual variable is changed?

Comment: Not unless it's on the window, and even then, it's very weird. Better to use an object with a getter/setter, or to use another design pattern entirely

Comment: That's what I assumed, but if there was a way, I could create some really clean code.. :)